# Icon/Button That changes based on boolean binding value in MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I've gotten this far with my XAML and wondering if I'm taking the right approach with regards to an icon/button to display data in a datagrid. I'm using Material Design.

I've got a boolean property in the viewmodel called "IsLocked". I want an icon in a column which will change to a lock or unlocked icon based on the value and I want to be able to click on the lock to change the value. I'm missing the button/click event. I'm trying to keep it in the XAML.

A bonus would be some UI feedback on mouseover to let the user know they can click it. How can I incorporate that too?

Is this the correct approach? How do I make it into something click-able?

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Is Locked">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon x:Name="LockIcon" Kind="LockOpenOutline" Foreground="Green"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isLocked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Kind" Value="Lock" TargetName="LockIcon"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" TargetName="LockIcon"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: You could use a ToggleButton which uses a trigger to swap icons in its Template depending on the value of IsChecked. Or just put the icons in its Content and swap with the trigger you’ve got. You would bind IsLocked to the ToggleButton’s IsChecked property. That’s the canonical way to do this. I can provide an example if needed but I bet you can find a few easily enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a converter which will return the PackIconKind and bind the isLocked property to the PackIcon with the converter.